# NUnit request-reply pattern

Tags: c#, nunit

I am working on a console application that calls certain tests from an external *dll* using a filter from a test suite. All these are made up with NUnit framework(version 2.5.0.9122).

I want to know if is possible that during a test, if after the method runs to make a call to the console application from the test external dll(sending a string message)can I send a string message from console application to the external dll test?(this has to be made multiple times).Moreover, is there a way for the `NUnit.Core.TestMethod.Run()` method to complete the process described above?